# javascript remove "disabled" attribute from html input

Tags: javascript, input, attributes

How can I remove the "disabled" attribute from an HTML input using javascript?

```
<input id="edit" disabled>
```

at onClick I want my input tag to not consist of "disabled" attribute.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Set the element's `disabled` property to false:

```
document.getElementById('my-input-id').disabled = false;
```

If you're using jQuery, the equivalent would be:

```
$('#my-input-id').prop('disabled', false);
```

For several input fields, you may access them by class instead:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('my-input-class');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled = false;
}
```

Where `document` could be replaced with a form, for instance, to find only the elements inside that form. You could also use `getElementsByTagName('input')` to get all input elements. In your `for` iteration, you'd then have to check that `inputs[i].type == 'text'`.

Comment: yes it works, but I had a lot of input need to do the same thing. Is there any shortcut for this? is this posible ('id1', 'id2', 'id3') ?

Comment: yes, it works! thanks. by the way there is a typo-error at geElementsBy . I thought it wouldn't work :)

Comment: This doesn't work in Safari (at least in the current 17.2). I'll have to use the other answer using `.removeAttribute('disabled')`, which seems to be more up to the standard.

Answer (score 63):

Why not just remove that attribute?

1. Vanilla JS is working in any major browser: `elem.removeAttribute('disabled')` [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)
2. jQuery: `elem.removeAttr('disabled')`

Comment: `jQuery("#success").removeAttr("disabled");` - this works for me, thanks!

Comment: vanilla js, removeAttribute isn't supported in IE.

Comment: @MarCrazyness `removeAttribute` seems to be supported in IE11. It's marked as `unknown` on can I use, so I just opened IE and checked if it works. It does.

Answer (score 16):

Best answer is just removeAttribute

```
element.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: in firefox, as nowadys (2020), the disabled attribute is active althoug it is set to false. firefox is just looking for the attribute itself. so best solution is to add or remove it for firefox, and this of course works for all major browsers.

Answer (score 4):

To set the `disabled` to false using the `name` property of the input:

```
document.myForm.myInputName.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can remove the disabled attribute by setting it to "false":

```
$("#input-id").attr("disabled", false)
```

Comment: Please, edit your answer to add some explanations.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
method 1 <input type="text" onclick="this.disabled=false;" disabled>
<hr>
method 2 <input type="text" onclick="this.removeAttribute('disabled');" disabled>
<hr>
method 3 <input type="text" onclick="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" readonly>
```

code of the previous answers don't seem to work in inline mode, but there is a workaround: method 3.

see demo https://jsfiddle.net/eliz82/xqzccdfg/

Comment: This two not working for me. ``method 1 <input type="text" onclick="this.disabled=false;" disabled>
<hr>
method 2 <input type="text" onclick="this.removeAttribute('disabled');" disabled>``

Comment: You downvoted this just because you don't properly know how to read an answer? Method 1 is from the David Hedlund response, method 2 is from the Dragos Rusu response. Once an element is disabled, "onclick" on that specific element will not work anymore in inline mode (I didn't tested external js mode). The only way is to simulate "disabled" is a little workaround using readonly attribute and some css. OR make an external "onclick" element like a button that will enable input using method 1 and 2 (that will work of course).