# javascript removeAttribute() doesn't remove "disabled"

Tags: javascript, xhtml

```
subject #2: <input type="text" name="subject2" id="sub2" class="i2" size="20" disabled> <br>  
  <button  onclick="document.getElementById('sub2').removeAttribute('disabled')"> add subject</button>
```

This is what i wrote, when i press the button the input field becomes white (becomes useable) for a second, and immediately returns to be grey and disabled. 
What did i do wrong? 
thank you

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/euhv59ts/)

Comment: try setting like this disabled="disabled"

Comment: Duplicate Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719961/javascript-remove-disabled-attribute-to-html-input

Comment: The problem is not that `removeAttribute()` isn't working, it's that your form is being submitted by the button click. Add `type=button` to the button HTML and try again.

Comment: @TrungNguyen this is a different problem than that one.

Comment: thank you Pointy that was the problem! thanks for the quick responses everybody.