# Disabled aspx button lose bootstrap class

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, textbox

I have this textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbid" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

form-control is a bootstrap class so the textbox gets the bootstrap look, if I disable the control from code using

```
tbid.Enabled = false;
```

the textbox loses the form-control class, after inspected the textbox I found out that it gets replaced by the aspNetDisabled class.

how I can prevent the change of class I want to keep the disabled button with the bootstrap look even if it is disabled.

Comment: Shouldn't "*bootstrap loop*" be "*bootstrap **look***"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Code
tbid.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: The same does not work on asp.net radiobutton. Could you please tell if you know

Comment: You can use this for radio button: `tbid.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: Thanks @Farzin. This is the only way to disable my asp.button in bootstrap. How can I enable it later on?

Comment: @Petronius You can enable it later in client side, by removing the disabled attribute by javascript or Jquery. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719961/javascript-remove-disabled-attribute-from-html-input

Answer (score 5):

I was having similar issues, but strangely only on some buttons on my page, so this piqued my curiosity...

Try using the CssClass instead of Class attribute, and it will work as expected.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Text="My Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score -2):

'on load write
tbid.Attributes("disabled")= "disabled"

Comment: Besides missing code formatting, this already has been answered in 2017 by [Farzin Kanzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41991422/7831383)

Comment: While this might be an asnwer to OPs question, its recommended to add more information on your suggested solution...