# need to add "child of div" to change disabled input

Tags: javascript, jquery

My web page has a set of input fields that are rarely used, I have to tab through each one of 50 input fields. I want to toggle the input field "disabled" attribute off on a mouse click on the individual field. The code below works. But I want to change #M1 to input child of the div.

```
<div onclick = "$('#M1').removeAttr('disabled')">">
<input type = "text" disabled id = "M1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript remove "disabled" attribute to html input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719961/javascript-remove-disabled-attribute-to-html-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot trigger click event of a disabled element. Try to wrap input by a div. Something like this.

```
<div onclick="$('#input_id').removeAttr('disabled')">
    <input id="input_id" disabled/>
</div>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/etv8h468/16/

Comment: Absolutely spot on and effective.

Comment: But is there any way to change "$('#input_id') to the child input field?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type = "text" id = "M1" 
 onclick ="document.querySelector('#M1').disabled = true;" />
```

This is the right way to do it.. Please try this

Comment: The input is initially disabled. Wouldn't onclick ="document.querySelector('#M1').disabled = false;" be correct?

Comment: but what do you want ?.. its disable at starting and if a user clicks on it. its should again visible? right?

Comment: Yes, that is the desired result!

Comment: This doesn't use jQuery, so I'm not sure why it's important to add the jQuery file...

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because the input is disabled and won't trigger the click event

try like this :

```
<div onclick = "document.querySelector('#M1').disabled = false;">
    <input type = "text" disabled id = "M1" />
</div>
```