# Toggle disable attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that has two radio buttons and a textarea. The textarea is disabled initially. When the user selects the 'Custom Message' radio button, the disabled property is removed and the textarea becomes editable.

Now if the user selects the 'Dummy Message' radio button, the textarea should become disabled again.

So far I have this code,

```js
document.getElementById('customMessageRadioButton').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (document.getElementById('customMessageRadioButton').checked) {
    document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').focus();
  }

  if (!document.getElementById('customMessageRadioButton').checked) {
    document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
});
```

```html
<input name="group1" id="dummy" type="radio" />Dummy Message
<input name="group1" id="customMessageRadioButton" type="radio" />Custom Message
<textarea disabled id="customMessageTextArea"></textarea>
```

The issue I am facing here is in this case - when I select the 'Custom Message' radio button first and then I go back and choose the 'Dummy Message' radio button, the textarea is not getting disabled.

Here is my [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jasoxekebo/edit?html,console,output)

P.S. I cannot use jQuery. Have to use only vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript remove "disabled" attribute to html input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719961/javascript-remove-disabled-attribute-to-html-input)

Comment: A change event isn't fired when a checkbox loses its `checked` status

Comment: @PatrickEvans It seems to be fired in my snippet.

Comment: @Barmar not when I just tested it. Going back to the dummy one after checking the custom checkbox leaves the textarea still enabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updated code based on your requirements, to make code simpler, I've used a flag to toggle the state of textarea.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
  
    <input name="group1" id="dummy" type="radio" onclick="toggleRadio(false)"/>Dummy Message
    <input name="group1" id="customMessageRadioButton" onclick="toggleRadio(true)" type="radio" />Custom Message
    <textarea disabled id="customMessageTextArea"></textarea>

  <script>
    
    function toggleRadio(flag){
      if(!flag) {
        document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
      } else {
        document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').removeAttribute("disabled");
        document.getElementById('customMessageTextArea').focus();
      }
      
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the updated jsbin : http://jsbin.com/gadupoheke/1/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

---

See the **Control** section if you don't want to read everything.

---

### Layout

---

If using more than one [form control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)...

- ...wrap everything in a `<form>` tag and give it an #id.
- ...separate form controls into groups and wrap them into `<fieldset>` tags.
- ...give the `<fieldset>`s and form controls #ids.

---

### Access

---

For complete control of a `<form>`...

- ...reference `<form>` tag with [Document Object **.forms** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms)

  - Dot notation and #id of form

    ```
    var formObj = document.forms.**FormID**
    ```
  - Or bracket notation and index  of zero for first form

    ```
    var formObj = document.forms[0]
    ```

---

- Next, collect all of the `<form>` tag's form controls using the [**.elements** property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements):

  ```
      var fields = formObj.elements
  ```

---

- Having done that, you may use [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) to reference any form control like a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) by referencing the elements property and #id of the form control:

  ```
      var set = fields.**fieldsetID**

      var sel = fields.**selectID**

      var btn3 = fields[2] // third form control
  ```

---

### Control

---

An element's attributes are initially set by hard coding them in HTML:

```
<fieldset disabled>
```

Or programmatically by JS methods like [**setAttribute()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

```
fieldsetObj.setAttribute('disabled', true)
```

Once an attribute is established, it should be referenced as a property if you want to change it:

```
fieldsetObj.disabled = false;
```

---

### Event Handling

---

[**Delegate Events**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) by registering events to the `<form>` tag.

```
 formObj.addEventListener('change', function)
```

Events that are the most applicable are:

[change, input, click, focus, blur, submit, reset](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

When all events are delegated to the `<form>` tag, the [Event Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) property **[Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)** will always refer to it. The element that was actually clicked, changed, received user input, gained focus, etc. is the origin of the event and can be referenced as [**Event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Once an event occurs, an event chain will enter the [capture phase](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm):

```
 e.currentTarget ===> e.target 

 <form> ============> <input>
```

Then the [target phase](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm):

```
 e.target changed

 <input checked>
```

Last is the [bubbling phase](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm) any other elements thereafter will be triggered by event if arranged to do so by its own default behavior, by being registered, or arranged to do so (ex. if x is this, then y is that):

```
 e.target =============> e.currentTarget

 <input checked> ======> <form>
```

---

### Tags

---

Many (but not all) form controls have special behavior that facilitates the operation of a `<form>` and its form controls:

- `<fieldset>`: apply the **[[disabled] attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/disabled-attribute/)** to it and all of the form controls nested within will be enabled/disabled as well.
- `<input type="radio">`: apply the [[name] attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) to a group of [radios] and they will be mutually exclusive when [[checked]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) (i.e. only one may be checked)
- Form controls with a [name] attribute will have their `value` sent to a server when the [`<form>` submits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).
- `<label>`: apply [[for] attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) and set its value to another form control's #id will sync said `<label>` and form control together. If a click event happens on said `<label>`, then the associated form control will behave as if it was clicked as well.

Not all of the inherit traits listed above are used in the Demo but are mentioned because the possibility is there if needed.

---

### Demo

**Details commented in Demo**

---

```js
// Reference the form tag
var main = document.forms.main;

// Collect all of #main form controls
var m = main.elements;

// Reference the radio group
var g0 = m.grp0;

// Register change event on #main
main.addEventListener('change', action);

// Define callback passing the Event Object
function action(e) {

  // if the changed element's [name] is "grp0"...
  if (e.target.name === "grp0") {

    // ...if "grp0" value is "on"...
    if (g0.value === 'on') {

      //...find the #set0 and enable it
      m.set0.disabled = false;
    } else {

      //...otherwise disable #set0
      m.set0.disabled = true;
    }

    //...otherwise if it isn't then ignore it.
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

/* for future exansion of form#main add if else  condition between
|| if and else conditions
*/
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <fieldset id='ctrl'>
    <label>Group 1&nbsp;On&nbsp;
    <input name="grp0" value="on" type="radio" checked/>
    &nbsp;Off&nbsp;
    <input name="grp0" value="off" type="radio" />
  </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='set0'>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const focusHandler = (e, status) => {
    if(status) {
      e?.target?.classList?.remove("text-grey");
      e?.target?.classList?.add("text-black");
    }else{
      e?.target?.classList?.remove("text-black");
      e?.target?.classList?.add("text-grey");
    }
  }

<Input className="text-grey" onChange={(e) => handleInputValue(e, "firstName")} onBlur={(e) => focusHandler(e, false)} onFocus={(e) => focusHandler(e, true)} placeholder="Enter your first name" />
```

you can use the above code for handling the toggle of the color code.